# Is there a way to get iframe-like functionality with ES Modules

Tags: html, iframe, es6-modules

I need to organize elements located on several different pages into one page and I'm trying to avoid using iframes since they are generally frowned upon. I tried using `<link rel="import" href="uri://element.host">` but Chrome is stating that HTML Imports will be deprecated in a future release and is recommending to use ES Modules instead. I wanted to see if there was a way with ES Modules that would allow you to import HTML elements from other pages.